# Taking two values from two list (Random Order) of tuples and multiplying

Tags: python, list, tuples, tf-idf

I have two lists and they are lists of tuples.

For example

```
List1 = [('zaidan', 0.0013568521031207597),('zimmerman', 0.0013568521031207597), ('ypa', 0.004070556309362279)]
List2 = [('zimmerman', 0.0013568521031207597), ('ypa', 0.004070556309362279), ('zaidan', 0.0013568521031207597)]
```

If the items were in the same order I could use the following code to multiply the two values:

```
val = [(t1, v1*v2) for (t1, v1), (t2, v2) in zip(tf,idf)]
```

But my issue is the order of one the lists outputs randomly so the code doesn't work. So essentially I need to see if the word in one list matches the word in the other and then multiply to get an output in a similar way as the list of tuples.

Answer (score 2):

This question excellently demonstrates the advantages of the `dictionary` data structure and how your problem could benefit from it. So first, we convert your list of tuples to dictionaries (`dict`-calls) and then you "combine" the two dicts as per your requirement to get the desired result.

```
lst1 = [('zaidan', 0.0013568521031207597),('zimmerman', 0.0013568521031207597), ('ypa', 0.004070556309362279)]

lst2 = [('zimmerman', 0.0013568521031207597), ('ypa', 0.004070556309362279), ('zaidan', 0.0013568521031207597)]

dct1 = dict(lst1)
dct2 = dict(lst2)

res = {k: v * dct2.get(k, 1) for k, v in dct1.items()}.items()
```

which produces:

```
dict_items([('zaidan', 1.8410476297432288e-06), ('zimmerman', 1.8410476297432288e-06), ('ypa', 1.656942866768906e-05)])
```

And if the `dict_item` data type is confusing, you can always cast it to a vanilla-list.

```
res = list(res)
print(res)
# [('zaidan', 1.8410476297432288e-06), ('zimmerman', 1.8410476297432288e-06), ('ypa', 1.656942866768906e-05)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to sort the dictionary before making it a list using the following. `sortDict1 = sorted(dct1, key=dct1.get)
    sortDict2 = sorted(dct2, key=dct2.get)` But this doesn't work. How would I order by value?

Comment: @godlypython Dictionaries cannot be ordered because they are not supposed to work like that. Why do you want to order it?

Comment: It was because, I needed an ordered version of the values which represent an "index" where the higher index value needs to be at the top and lower at the bottom. But i took a different approach thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i would tell you the easiest solution if your data are the same.
just sort it :

```
ls1 = sorted(ls1, key=lambda tup: tup[0])
ls2 = sorted(ls2, key=lambda tup: tup[0])

val = [(t1, v1*v2) for (t1, v1), (t2, v2) in zip(ls1,ls2)]
```

Comment: If i use `reverse = True` it messes up the values. How would I sort it from tup[1] from high to low

Answer (score 0):

If, for any reason, you do not want to use dictionary (although it is a superior solution) but want to do this with lists and tuples, what you are looking for is looping through the lists and checking for equality:

```
x = [('zaidan', 0.0013568521031207597),('zimmerman', 0.0013568521031207597), ('ypa', 0.004070556309362279)]

y = [('zimmerman', 0.0013568521031207597), ('ypa', 0.004070556309362279), ('zaidan', 0.0013568521031207597)]

z = []
for item in x:
    for _item in y:
        if item[0] == _item[0]
            z.append((item[0], item[1]*_item[1]))
```

At the end, `z` will be a list of tuples with the original string at the `0` index and the result of multiplication at the `1` index.

Comment: its will work but not good performance it is O(n^2),
and more memory to hold because you allocate a new memory space for z

Comment: @IdoBleicher Yes, I agree with you. The only presumable advantage of this solution is that it is visible what's going on "behind the scenes" which might be valuable for OP as they seem to be new to programming if they ask questions like these. Both your solution and Ev. Kounis's are better and more performant and overall better. The problem with your solution might arise if the data is not the same, however.